# How to "fill" area below geom_line predicted from model in ggplot2 / R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Please, find `My Data` below as sample of my dataset `nd`.

```
head(nd)
           y lnd
1: 0.3479943   0
2: 0.3740154   1
3: 0.3996300   2
4: 0.4217426   3
5: 0.4403666   4
6: 0.4572609   5
```

I have estimated a risk (denoted `nd$y`), which is the 5-year risk of death given the value corresponding to the continuous variable `nd$lnd`, which ranges from `nd$lnd==0,1,2,...,100`.

The predicted model look like this:

[image]

The ggplot was produced with the following script:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(nd), aes(x = lnd)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y, col = lnd),size=1) + theme(legend.position="none") +
  ggtitle("Lymph node density", subtitle = "Risk groups") + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="Evidence of metastatic burden per lymph node yield", breaks=seq(0,100,by=10), limits=c(0,100), label=c("0%\n LND 0%","10%","20%", "30%", "40%","50%","60%","70%","80%","90%","100%")) +
  scale_y_continuous(name="5-year risk of death", breaks = seq(0.3,1,by=.1),label=c("30%","40%","50%","60%","70%","80%","90%","100%")) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.15,1))
```

I would like to add a "filled" area below the `predicted geom_line()`

I have tried to demonstrate in Photoshop what I would like:

[image]

It is the area between `nd$lnd==0` and `nd$lnd==10` on the `x-axis` and below the corresponding `nd$y`-values for the specific `nd$lnd==0 - 10`

```
My Data

 nd <- structure(list(y = c(0.347994323433218, 0.374015418531899, 0.399629966119251, 
                        0.421742599051725, 0.44036657229005, 0.457260948328608, 0.474417648309559, 
                        0.493640865541709, 0.51488973428659, 0.537423493454801, 0.560430703662936, 
                        0.583045245963954, 0.604403317363394, 0.624118977779026, 0.642197094829998, 
                        0.658675856783435, 0.673612299496595, 0.687077654264746, 0.699153267191595, 
                        0.709927163750076, 0.719491270455802, 0.727939260908065, 0.735364964416906, 
                        0.741861259442995, 0.747519368138831, 0.752428469501541, 0.756675554521809, 
                        0.760345455237322, 0.763520989282281, 0.766283171326885, 0.768711452044572, 
                        0.770883953521034, 0.772877677101532, 0.774768665456197, 0.776627848464512, 
                        0.778481560816502, 0.780330067279974, 0.782173296838651, 0.784011178693879, 
                        0.785843642275446, 0.787670617252314, 0.78949203354347, 0.791307821328959, 
                        0.793117911060613, 0.794922233473425, 0.796720719596049, 0.798513300762498, 
                        0.800299908622762, 0.802080475154149, 0.803854932672504, 0.805623213843368, 
                        0.807385251693197, 0.809140979620611, 0.810890331407796, 0.812633241231531, 
                        0.814369643674837, 0.816099473738181, 0.81782266685046, 0.819539158880875, 
                        0.821248886149957, 0.822951785441022, 0.824647794011433, 0.826336849604117, 
                        0.828018890458497, 0.829693855322157, 0.831361683462205, 0.833022314676256, 
                        0.834675689303694, 0.836321748237183, 0.837960432933643, 0.839591685425587, 
                        0.841215448331989, 0.84283166486968, 0.844440278864124, 0.846041234760886, 
                        0.847634477636162, 0.849219953207282, 0.850797607844881, 0.852367388582385, 
                        0.853929243127316, 0.855483119871763, 0.857028967903429, 0.858566737015336, 
                        0.860096377717062, 0.861617841244557, 0.863131079570552, 0.864636045414574, 
                        0.866132692253169, 0.867620974331152, 0.869100846667809, 0.870572265071487, 
                        0.872035186145084, 0.873489567298754, 0.874935366756863, 0.87637254356889, 
                        0.877801057617996, 0.879220869629812, 0.8806319411832, 0.882034234714961, 
                        0.883427713533749, 0.884812341823933), lnd = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                       5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
                                                                       22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
                                                                       38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
                                                                       54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
                                                                       70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 
                                                                       86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    -101L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using geom_area for the subset of the data that you want to plot:

```
+ geom_area(aes(y = y), data = function(x) subset(x, lnd >= 0 & lnd <= 10))
```

The only issue is that it plots the area up to the Y = 0 axis, not just to the 30% that you colored in photoshop.

In case it helps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469000/ggplot-subset-a-layer-where-data-is-passed-using-a-pipe/53325802#53325802) I talk briefly about plotting a layer with only a subset of the default data.

Comment: Thanks @mgiormenti. What I want the geom_area to stretch from the y-axis? Eg. from nd$y==0.35 to nd$y==0.55 to the corresponding nd$lnd value? So basically the same, but defined on y-axis instead.

Comment: @ChristianMirianLarsen, as long it is always area under the curve, it doesn't matter how you filter the original data. You just need to modify the condition inside the subset() to fit your needs. In your example: data = function(x) subset(x, y >= 0.35 & y <= 0.55). I edited the answer to add a link to a related post, in case it helps.